# TCPDF multiple pages not display properly

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, tcpdf

I am using PHP Codeigniter While I will try to convert pdf for multiple pages, the next page data coming on the first pages. I want to convert pages data page wise. How can I do it?
I have followed this code:

**Controller:**

```
<?php
$createPDFFile="myData.pdf";
$data['user_data'] = $returnData;
$htmlContent = $this->load->view('admin/download_user_data', $data, TRUE);
$this->createPDF(FCPATH.'assets/generate_pdf/'.$createPDFFile, $htmlContent);
?>
```

**in View**

```
<?php
if(!empty($user_data)) {
  foreach($user_data as $pdata) {
?>
<!-- Here My html Code -->
<?php
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a break line after page data. I have got the success to added this line below of the last html tag.

```
<br pagebreak="true"/>
```

Hope it will be helpful for you.